# Random Sampling of vectors on the Complex Unit Sphere

Tags: complex-numbers, random, spheres

This is my first post in these forums.  Working in Mathematica, I would like to generate a large number (10000) of randomly sampled vectors on the complex unit sphere in n dimensions. I am not confident that I understand how area generalizes to the complex unit sphere, and would appreciate any input on the subject.

Thank you,
Jack

Comment: Can you provide a definition of the complex unit sphere? I found [a reference](https://www.math.washington.edu/~morrow/336_12/papers/hunter.pdf) which said it is the subset of $\mathbb C^n$ such that $z_1^2+\cdots+z_n^2=1$, but such a set is unbounded and so I'm not sure it even makes sense to sample from it uniformly.

Comment: Hi Rahul. Certainly, the complex unit sphere is the set of vectors with norm 1, where $||x||^2=x^* x$ ($x \in \mathbb{C}^n$ is a vector, $x^*$ its conjugate transpose). It is certainly bounded; no component of a vector I'm interested in may have a magnitude exceeding 1.

Comment: Ah, in that case, it's geometrically equivalent to the unit sphere in $\mathbb R^{2n}$ because $\mathbb C\cong\mathbb R^2$. So you just have to [sample from a real unit sphere](http://mathoverflow.net/q/24688/6979) and interpret the result as a vector in $\mathbb C^n$. In fact, since it's a one-liner in Mathematica, here you go: `({1, I}.#) & /@ Partition[Normalize@RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], 2 n], 2]`

Comment: Thanks for the one-liner! That certainly cleans up my code, and things seem to be working the way that I want them to.